# Check if all bundle items are available

Tags: magento-1.9, bundle-product

How can I check whether all bundle items are available?
I read somewhere about this `$_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()` but it doesn't work for me.

I need to make bundle product not saleable if one of bundle items is not saleable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to check whether the required child items of a bundle product are salable.

```
$isSalable = true;
$bundleProductId = 447;

$bundleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($bundleProductId);
$childrenIds = $bundleProduct->getTypeInstance(true)
    ->getChildrenIds($bundleProduct->getId(), true); // set second parameter to false to get not only required items
$childCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $childrenIds);

foreach ($childCollection as $child) {
    if (!$child->isSalable()) {
        $isSalable = false;
    }
}
```

After that you can use the variable `$isSalable` to decide whether the product is salable or not.

### EDITED

In this case will be better to rewrite the class "Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type" and rewrite the method "Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type::isSalable".
If you have your custom module you can do it as described below.
To rewrite the class edit the file "app/code/community/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml":

```
<config>
<modules>
    ...
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                <product_type>Namespace_Module_Model_Product_Type</product_type>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>
    </models>
    ....
```

Then create the file: "app/code/community/Namespace/Module/Model/Product/Type.php" and insert the following code:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Product_Type extends Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type
{
    public function isSalable($product = null)
    {
        $salable = parent::isSalable($product);

        $childrenIds = $this->getChildrenIds($this->getProduct($product)->getId(), true); // set second parameter to false to get not only required items
        $childCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $childrenIds);

        foreach ($childCollection as $child) {
            if (!$child->isSalable()) {
                $salable = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $salable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Do you have solution for various bundleProductId so I can use it in template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle.phtml?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you want it to appear, for bundled products the file would be

```
app/design/frontend/{theme}/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/availability.phtml
```

There you can update

```
    <p class="availability in-stock">
        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?></span>
        <span class="value"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock') ?></span>
    </p>
```

to

```
<?php
$selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getSelectionsCollection($_product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds());
$qty = false;
foreach ($selectionCollection as $option) {
    $product_id = $option->product_id;
    $bundleOption = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($bundleOption);
    if ($qty === false) {
        $qty = $stock->getQty();
    } else {
        $qty = min(array($qty, $stock->getQty()));
    }
}
?>

<p class="availability in-stock">
    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Availability:') ?></span>
    <span class="value"><?php echo $qty . ' ' . $this->helper('catalog')->__('In stock') ?></span>
</p>
```